# Auto delete published posts after a specific number of days in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am planning to start a newspaper based website (daily edition newspaper). I am building the site on WP.

Now, with demand of my clients, news items (WP posts in this case) need to be entirely deleted from the WP DB after 30 days. They do not even need an archive of this since they do not want to bloat the DB. Instead, they will keep a plan backup of the files/posts in their local system but want WP to complete remove those posts from the WP installation/DB.

Is is possible? If so, how to execute this on WP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you need WordPress for this? It seems overly complicated to force WordPress into a continuing process like that.

I would suggest just putting the following SQL statement in a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job (like a single .php file), and the rest will be handled by itself.

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

[Here's a good rundown on using cron to automatically do these kinds of this for you](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)

**Update**

Using the WordPress scheduling function we can provide a cron-like time-based scheduling of our post removal. This isn't a true cron job as it removes our posts only after a person has visited the site after 30 days, and not after 30 days regardless of visitors. However, it's the closest we'll get via WordPress and in this case the results would be the same. Add the following to functions.php or your plugin file.

```
/**
 * Add monthly interval to the schedules (since WP doesnt provide it from the start)
 */
add_filter('cron_schedules','cron_add_monthly');
function cron_add_monthly($schedules) {
$schedules['monthly'] = array(
  'interval' => 2419200,
  'display' => __( 'Once per month' )
);
return $schedules;
}
/**
 * Add the scheduling if it doesnt already exist
 */
add_action('wp','setup_schedule');
function setup_schedule() {
  if (!wp_next_scheduled('monthly_pruning') ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'monthly', 'monthly_pruning');
  }
}
/**
 * Add the function that takes care of removing all rows with post_type=post that are older than 30 days
 */
add_action( 'monthly_pruning', 'remove_old_posts' );
function remove_old_posts() {
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='post' AND post_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah, they want it on WP and hence, they will not keep many copies of the posts after a certain interval. 

Coming to my question -  if I place that statement in the wp-posts, will it not delete even the pages? I want only the posts (WP blog posts to be precise) because they want those posts to use as their news items. 

Please guide me if I am wrong here..

Comment: Quite right. I updated the query with post type and also wrapped it in a schedule function to go via WordPress. Updated the answer above.

Comment: Thanks once again for this code. However, is it necessary to wrap in in a schedule function too? I mean, placing alone the following code  in the `function.php` will not do?

`add_action( 'monthly_pruning', 'remove_old_posts' );
function remove_old_posts() {
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='post' AND post_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);"));
}`

Comment: Well, you can. But now you suddenly have a database call for every single visitor on your site, which can (and will) slow it down quite a bit. I would suggest against it.

Comment: oh many thanks.. surely I will go by your words. Just one quick question.. the client may ask to change the interval from 30 days to say 25 days or so. Shall I just change the INTERVAL 30 DAY statement only?

Comment: Well, we have two time-related things in our code above. The SQL statement, looking for posts older than 30 days, and the scheduling function, setting an interval in seconds. The interval for the scheduling is the part that says "2419200". To change this to once every 25 days, just take 60*60*24*25 (60secs in a minute times 60mins in an hour times 24hrs in a day times 25 days) = 2160000. You can of course run this once per day or once per week if you so choose, the INTERVAL 30 DAY part is the only thing that actually deletes the posts.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with everything and please check the checkmark symbol (✓) to the left of the answer if you're happy with it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can install WP-post expirator and setting it default to your number of days the post will be deleted after. it's work with WP-automatic too
https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/post-expirator/

Comment: Post Expirator seems to be abandonware unfortunately.